# foreach with two or more equal strings, how?

Tags: powershell

using test script on my printserver I'm getting some output:

```
Name                                                                                                                        
----                                                                                                                        
dnj-500.1                                                                                                                   
dnj-500.1                                                                                                                   
dnj-4000.1                                                                                                                  
3015.6                                                                                                                      
3015.05
```

I need to launch foreach or same process for this, but before that I need to delete one of `dnj-500.1` strings. How can I do this via powershell?

Comment: So you just want to delete the duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches work. Be sure, to select the right column (Name):

(I used get-process for demonstration purpose)

```
(get-process).count
133

(get-process | select name -Unique).count
106

(get-process | select name | Get-Unique -AsString).count
106
```

Comment: Hmmm, and if I have more than one column? `Name, Smth1, Smth2` and I need to kill strings with duplicate names?

Comment: add smth1, smth2 etc to the select Statement. `select Name, Smth1, Smth2`

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using `Sort-Object | Get-Unique -AsString`

`| select -unique` leaves only

```
Name                                                                                                                        
----                                                                                                                        
dnj-500.1
```

Kinda strange, but `Get-Unique` result is fine.

Comment: try `| select Name -unique`. This should just delete the duplicate names.